# Gutenberg Development vs Release version?

Tags: block-editor, development-strategy

I have a question about using Gutenberg Development version vs the release version. I am currently using the development version as it has some features still not available on release that are of particular interest to me (nested blocks), but I'm wondering about the following things:

1. Will it be possible to move to release version from development version without messing up my posts that used the development version of the plugin, once the release version catches up with the same features I've used?
2. Will moving to a newer development version from either

   - a release version, or...
   - an older development version

   mess up my posts? assuming that my posts made use of the same features from all the different versions.
3. Also what are the thiings I should be aware of from using the development version other then the bugs?.
4. For reference, this is the version of Guternberg I'm using -

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/

which I've been assuming is the development version, where as the release version is the one that automatically updates with WordPRess, am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: The development version is really for testing and development, it probably shouldn't be used on a production site just because it has features you want.

Comment: The version I'm using is found here - https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/ - I had assumed this was the development version, and that the release version was part of / updated with WordPress default features, am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: Yes. "Gutenberg" is the development version that's available as that plugin. The 'release version' is just the version of the block editor that's part of WordPress.